# Concat 2 css files

Tags: javascript, gulp

I had the app.css loading on a gulp task.

Works great but now I want to add Font Awesome.

```
var appCSS = 'app.css';

gulp.task('css', ['less'], function() {
    return gulp.src('app/**/*.css')
        .pipe(concat(appCSS))
        .pipe(gulp.dest(destination+'/css'))
        .pipe(rename({suffix: '.min'}))
        .pipe(cleanCSS())
        .pipe(gulp.dest(destination+'/css'));
});
```

This was my previous code. Now I added this bellow...

```
var faCSS = 'fa.css';
var v4Shims = 'v4-shims.css';

gulp.task('fa', function() {
    return gulp.src('app/**/*.css')
        .pipe(concat(faCSS))
        .pipe(gulp.dest(destination+'/css'))
        .pipe(rename({suffix: '.min'}))
        .pipe(cleanCSS())
        .pipe(gulp.dest(destination+'/css'));
});

gulp.task('v4Shims', function() {
    return gulp.src('app/**/*.css')
        .pipe(concat(v4Shims))
        .pipe(gulp.dest(destination+'/css'))
        .pipe(rename({suffix: '.min'}))
        .pipe(cleanCSS())
        .pipe(gulp.dest(destination+'/css'));
});
```

But it's not working. How can I do this?

Answer (score 0):

Your task should work like you did first time. Just need to add path to you second .css file. Let's describe the process:

```
gulp.task('css', ['less'], function() {
    return gulp.src('app/**/*.css')  // here you are getting all files to be processed, then fonts should be here and has .css type format
        .pipe(concat(appCSS))  // here you create output file, where all css would be combined all together
        ...
});
```

Comment: If you would like to add another paths, then gulp.src should looks like this: gulp.src(['app/**/*.css', '...another paths'])

Comment: what do you mean? Where is the fa and v4Shims ?

Comment: it's the same path

Comment: You have to place all css in one directory, which will be processed by gulp - gulp.src( /path to all your css to be processed/ ). And .pipe(concat( /output file/ )) make all in one. If you have fonts, just place it in the css directory in app. And use it.

Comment: There is no reason to make separate tasks for fa and V4Shims, - it will be processed all in one. 
That's enought:
gulp.task('fa', function() {
    return gulp.src('app/**/*.css')
        .pipe(concat(faCSS))
        .pipe(gulp.dest(destination+'/css'))
        .pipe(rename({suffix: '.min'}))
        .pipe(cleanCSS())
        .pipe(gulp.dest(destination+'/css'));
});

Comment: If you go instructions to the Font Awesome, it needs only add <link rel="stylesheet" href=.....  to your site.